# What's wrong with the declaration for Unity Range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The declaration raises an error: Must declare a body because it's not marked abstract, extract, or partial:

```
int Range(int minValue, int maxValue);

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
 .
 .   
 .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int Range(int minValue, int maxValue);
```

indeed looks like an abstract method signature for a method called `Range` taking two `int` parameters. That's what the compiler tells you: It is expecting you do implement that "method" like

```
int Range(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    return someIntValue;
}
```

---

> What I'm trying to do is use Random to generate an int in a range that will be used to index an array

Sounds like what you want to do would be something like

```
private int someRandomValue = Random.Range(minValue, maxValue);
```

**Note** though: This is only possible if `minValue` and `maxValue` here are `const` or at least `static` because the field will be intialized **before** the constructor of this type is executed => you can't use any instance fields (e.g. from the Inspector)

Otherwise you would rather need to initialize the field like e.g.

```
private int someRandomValue;

private void Awake ()
{
    someRandomValue = Random.Range(minValue, maxValue);
}
```

And if this is about an array you probably would want to do

```
private void Awake ()
{
    someRandomValue = Random.Range(0, theArray.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your statement `int Range(int minValue, int maxValue);` looks like a method declaration to the compiler. Without seeing the rest of the code in that file I can't easily determine what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use Random to generate an int in a range that will be used to index an array.

Comment: If I remove the declaration, Unity says " The name 'Range' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: I needed to qualify Range with Random. I didn't need the declaration at all.

Comment: @Perry It sounds like you should look up some basic C# language tutorials. This kind of problem can be avoided altogether with a 30 minute video on fundamentals.

Comment: You would think so, wouldn't you, but it was a momentary aberration of an aging mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the RangeAttribute from Unity

```
[Range(1, 6)]

public int integerRange;
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what OP is after .. from the comments on the other answer: `What I'm trying to do is use Random to generate an int in a range that will be used to index an array`

Comment: Yes, I tried it before. It works only in Unity Editor. If a number is generated by Random then it must be claimed by using Mathf.Clamp

Comment: No that's not true .. if a number is generated by a `Random.Range` then you already provide the min and (exclusive) max value right aways -> no need to clamp anything ...